# How to get the PyBindGen PyObject for a given C++ pointer?

Tags: c++, python, pybindgen

Given the `PyObject` created by `PyBindGen`, it's easy to get the pointer to the wrapped C++ object, just use the `obj` member in the struct:

```
typedef struct {
    PyObject_HEAD
    MyWrappedClass *obj;
    PyObject *inst_dict;
    PyBindGenWrapperFlags flags:8;
} PyMyWrappedClass;
```

However, let's say I have just `MyWrappedClass*`, and want to get the `PyObject` (if any, it might not exist) that wraps it. Is there any way to do this without maintaining my own dictionary of backpointers?

Comment: Why not save a pointer in the `MyWrapperClass` to the according `PyMyWrappedClass`?

Comment: I'd prefer to not burden the class with knowledge of the wrapper. I'm going to have hundreds of wrapped classes, so rather than doctor each of them I want a mechanism that works for any class. Thus keeping a hash or map or something from pointers to PyObjects.

Answer (score -1):

I would have added this as a comment if I had enough reputation as I'm not familiar with `PyBindGen`, but unless `inst_dict` is a dictionary of backpointers (as the name might suggest) I think you're out of luck (Unless you want to trawl through the Python heap to see if there are any instances of your class there).